# Python- Function not accepting number as 2 numbers, despite it having a comma

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is probably going to be fairly obvious but for some reason it just DOESN'T work.

The function I have is like this:

```
def hours(num,num2):

    return num , " hours and " , num2 , " minutes."
```

the function that's plugging into that is:

```
total(final) #this isn't really important, just wanted to show that it was a function
             #plugging into another function. This function puts out 2 numbers in a (n,m)
             #format.
```

which comes out with a number that's in a (n,m) format 
When I try to plug that (n,m) into the first function though, it doesn't work? I think it should because it's separated by a comma, and that's what the first function calls for, but I don't know.

Comment: You would have to call `hours(*total(final))` to force it to unpack.

Comment: You need the `*` stuff, as hinted by Mr Bothwell and explained in some of the answers, but I think that doesn't stop your troubles, as it seems to me that what your `hours` function returns is not what you expect... either `return num+" hours and "+num2 +" minutes."` or `return "%d hours and %d minutes."%(num, num1)` looks more useful to me --- but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def total(final):
    return (10, 20)

def hours(num1, num2):
    print num1, num2

result = total(4)
hours(*result)  #explode result tuple into two arguments

--output:--
10 20
```

A tuple, like `(10, 20)` is a single *thing*, and therefore it counts as only one argument.  It does NOT work like this:

```
    hours( (10, 20) )
             |   |
             V   V
def hours(num1, num2):
```

Instead it works like this:

```
  hours( (10, 20) )
         |------|
             |   
             V   
 def hours(num1, num2):
```

...which means you didn't provide an argument for num2.

However, writing:

```
hours( *(10, 20) )
```

explodes the tuple into two arguments:

```
hours(10, 20)
```

Comment: @bardofshipping, You're welcome.  As an alternative, you could define hours like this:  `def hours(numbers):`, then for the first line of the function body write:  `num1, num2 = numbers`

Answer (score 0):

Try calling *hours()* with the `*` to unpack the tuple:

```
time = (3, 15)
print(hours(*time))        # unpack the tuple
```

Here is the relevant section of the docs:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell based on the wording of your question, but I think what you're saying is that this:

```
hours(total(final))
```

doesn't work as expected, where `total` returns something like `return n,m`?

If so, you need to use what's commonly called the *splat* operator, python's syntax for unpacking arguments:

```
hours(*total(final))
```

The `*` operator, when used on an input parameter to a method, expands out a list/tuple/iteratable and uses the results as positional arguments to a method. I.E.

```
ex = 1,2
foo(*ex)
# is equivalent to
foo(1,2)
```

If you omit the `*` operator, a tuple would be passed together as a single positional argument, rather than being unpacked.